# PyInstaller compiled package raised 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-1

Tags: pyinstaller

Just with below two lines of codes in test.py:

```
s = '你好'
print(s)
```

It works well using:

```
>>> python3 test.py
你好
```

After packaging it using the bellow command:

```
>>> python3 -m PyInstaller --onefile test.py
```

And run again:

```
./test
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 3, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-1: ordinal not in range(128)
[7228] Failed to execute script 'test' due to unhandled exception!
```

Is it a PyInstaller issue?

Comment: no... and the default codec is utf-8 so you must be setting the codec to ascii somehow.

Comment: Then how to set it? I'm wring the tool that print should print all kinds of inputs from user. So I don't know what's the codec of the input string. Is there a general way to fix it?

Comment: use `s.decode('utf8')` but only if it's already encoded... in your example that isn't an encoded string.  do you realize that you are not running the compiled executable?  The compiled app will appear in a folder called `dist`.  You are still running the py script

Comment: yes, the 's' is a string, so decode doesn't work. No, I run the under ./dist folder: ./test

Comment: I am unable to reproduce this issue... what os, version of pyinstaller and python version are you using?

Comment: strange, it could run successfully under mac os terminal (zsh). My reported issue is under VSCode 1.74.0 terminal (zsh).

Comment: oh... so the problem is with your terminal display not pyinstaller.

Comment: Versions: vscode=1.74.0, PyInstaller=5.6.1, Python=3.11.0 Suspect it's a vscode terminal issue

Comment: VSCode version 1.74.1 fixed the issue. It's a vscode bug